# Send request to the custom host/site through the Tor network programmatically, without Tor Browser installing (C++ Qt, using Winsock2)

Tags: windows, socks, torsocks

Show me please any minimum-worked example of C++ Qt (or pure C++) code, which sends request via sockets to IP `123.45.67.89` on port `12345` **through the Tor network** - without Tor Browser installing, of course.

Comment: "without Tor Browser installing, of course." by this do you mean it actually implements the OR protocol? Or that it just uses Tor's SOCKS Port?

Comment: Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40403372/send-request-to-the-custom-host-site-through-the-tor-network-programmatically-w) you basically want someone to reimplement the OR protocol for you. Well the spec is on https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git good luck writing it.